# Why Array controller with itemcontroller has different 'this' object?

Tags: ember.js

I defined an arraycontroller as:

```
Kiford.ChatboxesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
itemController: 'chatbox',
currentParticipant: undefined,
actions:{
    react: function(){
       console.log(this);
    },
}
```

and I have a template using this controller:

```
{{#each item in controller}}
    <div {{action 'react'}}>test react</div>
{{/each}}
```

when I clicked on the div with 'test react' text, the output of console prints value of this:

[image]

But when I send action from another controller as:

```
this.get('controllers.chatboxes').send('react');
```

The output value of 'this' is:

[image]

Apparently, the two 'this' are completely different objects, Why?

and How I can access the first 'this' object with child controller object when I send action from other controller?

**Edited** : **Additional Code:**

main.hbs:

```
<div class="out-box">
    {{render "chatboxes" model}}
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

route main:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('main', {path: '/' }, function(){}}
```

chatboxes.hbs:

```
{{#each item in controller}}    
........
{{/each}}
```

main controller:

```
APP.MainController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['chatboxes'],

    meetingCallback: function(operation){
        switch(operation.type){
            case 'sendMessage':
                this.get('controllers.chatboxes').send('react');
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `ArrayControllers`, `ObjectControllers`, `itemController` are all being deprecated, so I wouldn't spend a lot of time trying to figure this out.

I see what's going on now, when you use `render` it creates a new instance.  `needs` grabs the singleton instance of the controller (which will be different from render).

I'd recommend using a component and passing in the properties that are necessary to accomplish what you are trying to do.  http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/components/defining-a-component/

Comment: I confirmed the output of  'this'  is after the item controllers are created. When send action from other controller, I can not iterate child controller as you wrote: the length of _subcontrollers is 0, you can see it on attached image.

Comment: And your controller is a parent of the controller that's attempting to call it, yes?

Comment: I do not understand what does the word "your controller" mean. the so called "other controller" in my comment has no relationship with these array controller and itemcontrollers, it is just another controller to relay event from websocket.

Comment: Okay, correct me where I'm wrong here, is the "other controller" associated with a route?  Will you include your router, and the websocket/controller code?  Which route are you on when the websocket/controller code is attempting to talk to the chat boxes controller?

Comment: I edited my problem and added some code, the other controller is the main controller, it is related to main route. I am on main route when action is sent.

Comment: Updated answer, `render` is awesome, but it isolates itself from the rest of the app in terms of being able to talk to it